# Verifying time-invariance for spatial gradients of air pollution?

Tags: spatial-statistics, time, kriging, geostatistical-analyst, air-quality

I have data from a network of NO2 passive samplers. Measurement are repeated in the same positions in different years. 
I need to verify if spatial gradients in air pollution remain constant in time, independently from the absolute NO2 measured concentrations (e.g. in a certain area pollution is always higher than in other areas).
Which statistical/geostatistical analysis should I use?

PS. I am wandering if a possible solution could be to normalize each sampled NO2 concentration by the average concentration of all samplers in each year, then do some kriging and compare in some way different maps...